# Resultados repetidos consulta PDO FETCH_ASSOCC en ciclo anidado

Tags: php, pdo, foreach

Tengo un problema y no sé como solucionarlo.

Tengo estas dos funciones en **funciones.php** :

```
function getModulosRecurso($idmateria){
    $base= new Database;
    $base = Database::conectar();

    $query= $base->prepare("SELECT id_modulo FROM recursos_materia WHERE id_materia= :id");
    $query->execute(['id' => $idmateria]);



    $result= $query->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_NUM);

return ($result);
}

function getRecurso($idmodulo){
    $base= new Database;
    $base = Database::conectar();

    $query= $base->prepare("SELECT * FROM recursos_materia WHERE id_modulo= :id");
    $query->execute(['id' => $idmodulo]);



    $result= $query->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

return ($result);
}
```

Una me trae solamente el módulo, otra, todos los campos (las 2 me devuelven las cosas como quiero).

Después donde obtengo los recursos hago lo siguiente, primero obtengo módulos con la función que me trae solamente el módulo, hago un `foreach` para que recorra donde se imprime el número del módulo, después obtengo todos los recursos mediante la función y le paso como parámetro el módulo del recurso:

```
$modulos= getModulosRecurso($idmateria);




foreach($modulos as $row){
    $modulo =null;
        $listarecursos= null;


$modulo.= $row[0];

    $listarecursos.=<<<EOF
    <h3 style="color: #1d1c1a;">{$modulo}</h3>
    <span class="dropdown">
    <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Filtrar recursos por <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Videos</a>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Textos</a>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">PDFs</a>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Exámenes</a>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Encuestas</a>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Otros</a>
    </div>
    </span>
    <br>
    <br>


EOF;

$resultado= getRecurso($modulo);



    foreach($resultado as $rowa) {

        $nombre= null;
        $descripcion= null;
        $descarga= null;
        $nombre.= $rowa['nombre'];
        $descripcion.= $rowa['descripcion'];
        $descarga.= $rowa['descarga'];
        $listarecursos.=<<<EOF
        <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead style="background-color: #fdd306">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Accion</th>
                <th scope="col">Descripcion</th>
                <th scope="col">Descarga</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>


                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <p><ion-icon name="document-text"></ion-icon>{$nombre}</p>
                                </td>
                                <td>{$descripcion}</td>
                                <td>
                                {$descarga}
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
EOF;



    }

}
```

Hago un `echo` más abajo de `listarecursos`. 
Y me trae repetido todos los campos 4 veces cada uno. Traté de hacer de todo ya, no sé para donde agarrarlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por último, mi base de datos de los recursos es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estás leyendo todo desde la misma tabla (recursos_materia), tanto para los módulos como para los recursos. Lógicamente, vas a obtener valores repetidos, porque hay 4 filas con id_modulo = 1

Primera opción: Cambia la consulta para seleccionar solo los **distintos**

```
$query= $base->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT id_modulo FROM recursos_materia WHERE id_materia= :id");
```

Ventajas: No necesitas modificar otras partes de tu código
Desventajas: Sigues consumiendo más recursos de los necesarios

Segunda opción: Lee todos los registros y ordena por módulo:

```
function getRecursos($idmateria){
    $base = new Database;
    $base = Database::conectar();

    $query= $base->prepare("SELECT * FROM recursos_materia WHERE id_materia= :id ORDER BY id_modulo");
    $query->execute(['id' => $idmateria]);
    $result= $query->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $result;
}
```

Ventajas: Ahorras recursos porque obtienes todo en una sola consulta
Desventajas: Solo te quedaría por resolver la lógica para mostrar las opciones de cada módulo, pero es realmente sencillo.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!!! Lo voy a probar pero entendí perfectamente lo que me dijiste. Cualquier cosa igual te aviso, pero millones de gracias.

Comment: Hola, no pude hacerlo de tu manera, de ninguna de las dos maneras

Comment: @JeronimoLedesma, por favor actualiza tu pregunta para ver cómo queda el código usando la consulta con `SELECT DISTINCT`, porque solo con ese cambio en la primera función te debería mostrar los resultados como quieres.

Comment: Ahí me hice una autorespuesta

Comment: La cosa aquí es: Si resolviste el problema de repetidos, entonces marca esta respuesta como aceptada y crea una nueva pregunta para el formato, con gusto te ayudo, pero no mezcles. Si aún estás recibiendo duplicados, entonces edita tu pregunta para agregar información y ver cómo solucionarlo.

Comment: Ah bueno perdón pensé que como era el tema seguía relacionado tendría que seguir en el mismo topico. Disculpa, ahora lo publico !